# using vbNewLine when writing a file and split one line into two lines

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with a fixed width format file. Trying to create a file format that has two alternating rows - record type AA and record type BB

input file looks like this:

[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar6cR.png)

sample output file:

```
AA000022018110112345678D9SDRWSANON8602P              000005000ADSK      SRO     PN  0001080000000                                                                                                      
BB0000220181101                        ARPI                                                                                                                                                            
AA000032018110112345678D9BDRWSANON8602H              000005000ADSK      SRR     PN  0001080000000                                                                                                      
BB0000320181101
```

the code that writes the file is as follows; trying to figure out where to put the & vbNewLine & code so that it splits up the file into two rows.

```
Sub exportBD()
 Dim UsedRows As Long
 Dim UsedColumns As Long
 Dim lRow As Long
 Dim i As Long, j As Long
 Dim rng As Range
 
 Open Environ("userprofile") & "\Dfile" & Format(Date, "mmddyy") & "." & Format(TIME, "hhmm") & ".txt" For Output As #1
 
 With shtBD
 
 'Header
 
 lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lRow, 1), .Cells(lRow, 2))
  
 UsedRows = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
 UsedColumns = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
 
Set Header = shtBD.Range("A2:F2")

Print #1, Join(Array(shtBD.Range("A2"), shtBD.Range("B2"), shtBD.Range("C2"), shtBD.Range("D2"), shtBD.Range("E2"), shtBD.Range("F2")))
 
 For i = 3 To UsedRows
     For j = 1 To UsedColumns - 1
        Print #1, .Cells(i, j); " ";
    Next j
 Print #1, .Cells(i, UsedColumns)
 Next i
 End With
 
Print #1, "UTRL     " & UsedRows - 2
 
  Close #1
  
 MsgBox "Finished...", vbInformation
End Sub
```

where would i put in the & vbNewLine so that output shows up in two lines? i know it's somewhere in and around the 'for..next' loops towards the bottom, but not quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 3 To UsedRows
    For j = 1 To UsedColumns - 1
        ' <-- you would either add it here, or within-, or after the next line:
        Print #1, .Cells(i, j); " ";
    Next j
    Print #1, .Cells(i, UsedColumns)
Next i
```

But most likely a neater approach would be define a separator variable, near the top of your function (where all the other `Dim` statements are):

```
Dim sColumnSep as String
```

And then doing something like

```
For i = 3 To UsedRows
    For j = 1 To UsedColumns - 1
        If j = 99999 Then
            sColumnSep = VbCrLf;
        Else
            sColumnSep = " ";
        End If
        Print #1, .Cells(i, j) & sColumnSep;
    Next j
    Print #1, .Cells(i, UsedColumns)
Next i
```

Where `99999` should be the number for the last column prior to the newline (not sure what the right value is, most likely `5`).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. was able to fix the code by using:

```
 For i = 3 To UsedRows
     For j = 1 To UsedColumns - 1
        If j = 39 Then
            sColumnSep = vbNewLine
        Else
            sColumnSep = " "
        End If
        
        Print #1, .Cells(i, j) & sColumnSep;
           
     Next j
         
    Print #1, .Cells(i, UsedColumns) & " "

 Next i
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).